# In React, on button click, display alert for 5 seconds, then hide alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, form-submit, use-state

We are using this CSS which is for an animation where the div (or for any element using the `animate` class) disappears after 4 seconds.

```
@keyframes FadeAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
.animate {
  animation: FadeAnimation 4s ease-in .1s forwards;
}
```

In react, we have a button that can be clicked, and when the button is clicked, the `animate` class is added to our Alert div (which was previously hidden):

```
const [isUpdating, setIsUpdating] = useState(false)
const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false)
const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    setIsUpdating(true);

    // Axios request to update user info
    try {
        const updateUserObj = { fullName, email };
        const userId = ...;
        const updateResponse = await Axios.put(`/users/update/${userId}`, updateUserObj);
        
        // Set States Following Successful Login
        setIsUpdating(false);
        setShowAlert(true); // setting to true to display hte alert
    } catch (err) {
        setIsUpdating(false);
    }
};

return (
    <Button onClick={handleButtonClick}>
        {`${isUpdating ? 'Updating...' : 'Submit Button'}`}
    />
    <Alert
        className={`modal-alert ${showAlert ? 'animate' : ''}`}
        variant='success'
    >
        Your profile was updated
    </Alert>);
)
```

This button click handles submitting a form which updates info for a user in our database, and it also displays an alert by updating the `showAlert` state to true, which adds `animate` as a class on the alert.

Our problem is that this approach only works for the **first** click of the button, but not subsequent clicks. When the button is first clicked, `showAlert` is set to `true`, and nothing happens that ever turns this back to `false`. The CSS handles hiding the alert after 4 seconds, but the button is no longer usable.

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
  const [isUpdating, setIsUpdating] = useState(false)
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false)
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setIsUpdating(true);
    setIsUpdating(false);
    setShowAlert(true); // setting to true to display hte alert
  };

  let alertClass = showAlert ? 'modal-alert animate' : 'modal-alert';
  let alertStyles = showAlert ? {} : { opacity: 0, visibility: 'hidden', pointerEvents: 'none' };
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className='submit-button' 
        onClick={handleButtonClick}
      >
        Submit Button
      </div>
      <div
          className={alertClass}
          style={alertStyles}
          variant='success'
      >
          Your profile was updated
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.modal-alert {
  border: 1px solid #222222;
}

.submit-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  &:hover {
    background: darkblue;
  }
}

@keyframes FadeAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
.animate {
  animation: FadeAnimation 4s ease-in .1s forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`onAnimationEnd`](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/events.html#animation-events) synthetic event to modify your state back:

```
<Alert
  className={`modal-alert ${showAlert ? 'animate' : ''}`}
  variant='success'
  onAnimationEnd={() => setShowAlert(false)}
>
```