# How to make a button appear after 5s in react

Tags: css, reactjs

Exactly what the title says.
If anyone has any solutions in either CSS or js i would appreciate it

````
  animation-delay: 5s;
  animation-duration: 1ms;
  animation-name: slidein;
  opacity: 100;

}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
      opacity:0;
  }

  to {
 opacity: 100;
  }
}```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64178186/in-react-on-button-click-display-alert-for-5-seconds-then-hide-alert

maybe this can help you

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so how I would go about would be as follows:

1. Create a variable called notVisible and set it to true
2. Create the
   button and set its `hidden` property to the variable you created
3. Use a new promise and set it to resolve after 5 seconds, changing the
   variable to false then this should have your button appear

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)).then((res)=>{setNotVisible(false)});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had the exact problem this is how I would do it.

1. Make a variable to monitor state of the button

```js
const [isVisible, setVisible] = useState(false)
```

2. Now you use a call back in `setTimeout` which will trigger after `5000ms`.
3. So after 5000ms call back will do `setVisible(true)`
4. Your button can have an expression which will add a class if the value of `isVisible` is `true`

```js
<button 
    style = {{display: 'None'}} 
    className = {isVisible ? '' : 'MyClass'}
>
    Click Me
</button>
```

Where `MyClass` is your class which will have all the properties of a button which will make it visible.

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
```

Now in useEffect to change visibility after page loading:

```
useEffect(() => {
setTimeout(() => {
  setIsVisible(true);
}, 5000)
}, []);
```

Now in your button: toggle the visibility according to your state using a ternary operator.